# relocate "Users" folder to another volume drive on windows server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

Can someone provide steps on how to move the Users folder from the C drive to another drive on Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 0):

please provide a bit more detail. Are you referring to the 'my documents' or the actual user profile folder?

Comment: It would be the entire "Users" folder that sits in the main directory of the C: drive on the server.  https://imgur.com/a/qg1ooTd

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done this in the past. I have had a lot of success with this with no issues in Windows, but please note YMMV:

1. Boot the computer with a Windows Installation CD.
2. Choose "Repair my Installation" and then choose "Command Prompt"
3. Navigate to different drive letters (e.g. c:, d:, e:, f:, etc) to figure out where your current Users directory is and where you'd like to move relative to how the Windows boot mapped the drives.
4. Copy your Users directory from where it currently is to where it should be, e.g.:

   xcopy /h /s /E /B /Y /V /C /K /X F:\Users D:\Users
5. Move your current Users directory to another name such as Users2:

   move Users User2
6. Create a symbolic link from where Users was, to where you copied the folder.

   mklink /J Users D:\Users
7. Reboot and validate that everything is proper (e.g. Create a new file in your Documents, and validate it shows on the other drive / location)
8. Delete the copy of the Users2 Directory.

NOTE: Some folders you will need to go into "Advanced" and take ownership of the file before you can delete it.